# DIY toroidal transformer spot welder

Tags: transformer, current-limiting, toroid

I've put together a toroidal transformer using a core suitable for 1500VA. The primary coil is around 70 turns with the secondary coil being just one. When I plug it into the mains (110VAC), I just get a second of humming and the circuit breaker goes.

I'm guessing I'm missing something obvious but how do I stop the current from building up to the point it overloads.  I'd like to keep it at 1kw continuous.

I've watched a number of YouTube videos, can't see what I'm doing differently.

Saturation flux density is 20350 gauss.

Comment: You better use a couple MOT’s cause your inductance is too low and you must not make R too high and the  ferrite is saturating. It may be possible but not without some complete design parameters

Comment: What's your core's saturation field?

Comment: @Hearth assuming saturation flux density, that's 20350 gauss

Comment: @Chris And what peak flux density do you calculate?

Comment: @Hearth Excuse the ignorance, but I've not made any other calculations. I've just put this together based on videos etc

Comment: @Hearth Is it worth salvaging what I have or should I just get a couple of MOTs?

Comment: @Chris I couldn't say without much more information. I recommend doing the calculations to see if your core is saturating and how you might prevent it.

Comment: @Hearth I'm very much learning, what calculations would those be? I'm just copying off YouTube.

Comment: You may want to look up some tutorials on electromagnetics, then. Explaining the details here would be too broad for this site.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75  in simple terms, would MOTs be built such that I'd avoid the problem in running into at the moment?

Comment: Yes since MOT with bulk film cap raised impedance to be less than 20A breaker+ fuse for America or maybe 10 breaker for EU 240V.

Comment: well, I don't know how your breaker is set up or the rest... a very possible cause could be inrush current, for up to three line cycles current goes up to 25 times the regular current of the transformer and moves down when. This happens right when you turn it on so it matches your story.

there are several setups on how to reduce inrush current so it is possible you might have to look up into that as well.

Answer (score 1):

A toroid core intended for AC is rarely equipped with a gap (which would
defeat the self-shielding property), so it may remain magnetized for a 
while after power is disconnected.   In the case of a spot welder, with
unknown secondary loading, saturation is highly likely to be a problem
(very high inrush current) if the AC waveform is presented (the switch
closed) at some random time.

Such a core just isn't right for this kind of many-short-bursts activation.